# C + + and PCRE question

Tags: c++, pcre

I want to ask you how to match this MD5 hash in C + + with PCRE:

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

mysite.com FALSE   /       FALSE   0       SSID    25f11fe19d2ffd98378c57432cd8d4f2
```

Answer (score 0):

Umm.

```
/\S+/
```

would match one or more non-space characters. To be more specific,

```
/[a-f0-9]+/
```

would match MD5 sums because they are numbers and letters a-f.

Comment: An MD5 sum is always 128 bits, so `[a-f0-9]{32}` would be better.